# XPath of text from child element

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I'm trying to get an XPath to select text from a web page. Upon inspecting element, I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isRTJ.png). I'm trying to get `Florida State University`. When I right-click to copy XPath, I get this:

```
//*[@id="clue_J_3_2"]/em
```

However, when I run the python code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
game_url = 'http://www.j-archive.com/showgame.php?game_id=5566'
page = requests.get(game_url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content) 
path = '//*[@id="clue_J_3_2"]/em'
print tree.xpath(path)
```

the output I get is `[]`. I have tried many variations including:

- `//*[@id="clue_J_3_2"]/em/text()`
- `/*/[@id="clue_J_3_2"]/em`
- `//*[@id="clue_J_3_2"]//em[@class="correct_response"]/text()`

Please let me know how to fix my XPath to get the text I want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath is correct, but you need to click the element to be able to get to your desired xpath in the DOM. When I inspected the page in question, I got this.

```
<div onmouseover="toggle('clue_J_3_2', 'clue_J_3_2_stuck', '(Grant: What is Florida?)<br /><br /><em class=&quot;correct_response&quot;>Florida State University</em><br /><br /><table width=&quot;100%&quot;><tr><td class=&quot;wrong&quot;>Grant</td><td class=&quot;right&quot;>Holly</td></tr></table>')" onmouseout="toggle('clue_J_3_2', 'clue_J_3_2_stuck', 'In 1858 this university went co-ed when it took on the Tallahassee Female Academy')" onclick="togglestick('clue_J_3_2_stuck')">
```

So, looks like you'll have to parse the `div`'s `onmouseover` all by yourself. Or perhaps use selenium, but I wouldn't go that far.

```
toggle_js = tree.xpath('//div[@onclick="togglestick(\'clue_J_3_2_stuck\')"]/@onmouseover')[0]
# 'toggle(\'clue_J_3_2\', \'clue_J_3_2_stuck\', \'(Grant: What is Florida?)<br /><br /><em class="correct_response">Florida State University</em><br /><br /><table width="100%"><tr><td class="wrong">Grant</td><td class="right">Holly</td></tr></table>\')'
answer = re.findall(r'correct_response">(.*)</em>', str(toggle_js))
answer[0].strip() if answer else None
# 'Florida State University'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked source code of this page, I found that some element is dynamically created by javascript, as `request` can only get HTML code, so this is why you get an empty result when using `tree.xpath(path)`.
After I changed path to `'//*[@id="clue_J_3_2"]`,I got some text.
Remember, if you want to use print , you should do like this : `print tree.xpath(path)[0].text`.